# How can I create hyperlinks and mailto links in a node?

Tags: 7, theming

I need to create external hyperlinks to external pages and also mailto links. But when doing so, Drupal prints the code, ie `<a href...`.

I downloaded a link module which was okay except you could not remove the http from the page display, and also it would not code a mailto link.

How can this be done in Drupal 7, do I have to install some sort of editor? If so, which one?

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you probably want to look at Text Filtering options.

If your content creators are all trusted, you can allow them to input unfiltered content directly in to the node.  The text filter I like to use for this is "PHP Code"... it literally lets you put in whatever you want.

If they're less trustworthy, consider using an editor like TinyMCE.  It will let you set which tags are allowed and gives you a nifty interface to edit the node with.

Comment: what do you mean?? 'The text filter I like to use for this is "PHP Code"...'

Comment: @TopTomato   check this out:  https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/filter

Comment: Don't recommend the PHP filter. That's bad practice.